How to create mouse interaction for particles (PointsMaterial) so that the mouse movement distorts shape of object
I’m a bit stuck. I am trying to create an effect with Three.js where on moving the mouse over some particles, the movement distorts the shape of the object the particles are creating something almost like this. What I currently have is this:
import * as THREE from "three";
import { SimplexNoise } from "three/addons/math/SimplexNoise.js";

// general setup, boring, skip to the next comment

console.clear();

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color("dimgray");

// var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(30, innerWidth / innerHeight);
// camera.position.set(4, 2, 8);
// camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
  30,
  window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
  0.1,
  1000
);

camera.position.z = 8;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
renderer.setAnimationLoop(animationLoop);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  camera.aspect = innerWidth / innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  renderer.setSize(innerWidth, innerHeight);
});

// next comment

// some waves with simplex noise

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(6, 4, 150, 100),
  pos = geometry.getAttribute("position"),
  simplex = new SimplexNoise();

var waves = new THREE.Points(
  geometry,
  new THREE.PointsMaterial({ size: 0.02 })
);
waves.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(waves);

// that's all folks

function animationLoop(t) {
  for (var i = 0; i < pos.count; i++) {
    var x = pos.getX(i),
      y = pos.getY(i),
      z = 0.5 * simplex.noise3d(x / 2, y / 2, t / 2000);

    pos.setZ(i, z);
  }
  pos.needsUpdate = true;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

Any ideas that could lead me down the right path? Thanks.

Did you try searching google? A quick search for "three.js interactive particles" yielded many results.

I looked for hours to no avail. The one that there are examples of is the one where the mouse interaction disperses the particles i.e. this effect. I would like to do a deformation i.e. this effect.

Basically, as 2pha mentioned, there are many examples with code for this type of effect. In the example you gave, you simply create an object and change its material to points, on the cursor you create an invisible sphere that will serve as an object to scatter particles. You will get a better effect by creating your own shader with particles, and then add postprocessing (bloom). If you don't need 3D objects, you can achieve the same on canvas by changing for example jpg to particles.
Here is simple example:


<script type="importmap">
  {
"imports": {
  "three": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/build/three.module.js",
  "three/addons/": "https://unpkg.com/three@0.169.0/examples/jsm/"
}
  }
</script>

<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "three";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true });
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        const p_no = 1000;
        const p = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        const positions = new Float32Array(p_no * 3);
        const originalPositions = new Float32Array(p_no * 3);
        const radius = 2;

        for (let i = 0; i < p_no; i++) {
            const phi = Math.acos(1 - 2 * Math.random());
            const theta = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
            positions[i * 3] = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.cos(theta);
            positions[i * 3 + 1] = radius * Math.sin(phi) * Math.sin(theta);
            positions[i * 3 + 2] = radius * Math.cos(phi);
            originalPositions[i * 3] = positions[i * 3];
            originalPositions[i * 3 + 1] = positions[i * 3 + 1];
            originalPositions[i * 3 + 2] = positions[i * 3 + 2];
        }

        p.setAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(positions, 3));
        const p_mat = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00, size: 0.1 });
        const p_sys = new THREE.Points(p, p_mat);
        scene.add(p_sys);

        camera.position.z = 5;

        const mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', (event) => {
            mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
            mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
        });
        
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        });

        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            const p_pos = p_sys.geometry.attributes.position.array;
            let isDistorted = false;

            for (let i = 0; i < p_pos.length; i += 3) {
                const dx = p_pos[i] - mouse.x * 5;
                const dy = p_pos[i + 1] - mouse.y * 5;
                const distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

                if (distance < 1) {
                    const distortionAmount = (1 - distance) * 0.5;
                    p_pos[i] += (dx / distance) * distortionAmount;
                    p_pos[i + 1] += (dy / distance) * distortionAmount;
                    isDistorted = true;
                } else {
                    const orgX = originalPositions[i];
                    const orgY = originalPositions[i + 1];
                    const orgZ = originalPositions[i + 2];
                    p_pos[i] += (orgX - p_pos[i]) * 0.05;
                    p_pos[i + 1] += (orgY - p_pos[i + 1]) * 0.05;
                    p_pos[i + 2] += (orgZ - p_pos[i + 2]) * 0.05;
                }
            }

            p_sys.geometry.attributes.position.needsUpdate = true;
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
</script>



